# JMESPath array flatten + create key:value pair

Tags: json, jmespath

I have a JSON object which I'd like to turn into a dictionary.

The object looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "votes": [
      {
        "id": "0x0d185b44dc6a9e4077d44a29fccc22d1f6238192107d08afa890a1bdddc01e10",
        "voter": "0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062"
      },
      {
        "id": "0xf141aa62dc57b20fb6ea1197df44ba0ab4de166c8c19302553065788812beea1",
        "voter": "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA"
      },
      {
        "id": "0xf141aa62dc57b20fb6ea1197df44ba0ab4de166c8c19302553065788812beea1",
        "voter": "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm looking to grab the voter values and create an object like the below.

I'm shooting for the preferred result, but if it's not possible, either OK results will do.

OK results

```
  "0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062": "1",
  "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA": "1"
}
```

```
  "0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062": "1",
  "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA": "1",
  "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA": "1"
}
```

Preferred result

```
  "0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062": "1",
  "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA": "2",
```

Testing so far:
Using
`@|data.votes[].join(',',[voter, '1'])`
I could get a closeish response e.g. `"0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062,1"` but not what I'm looking for.

Please can anyone help for either satisfactory result or preferred result?

Edit:
Using `@|data.votes[].join('":"',[voter, '1'])`
I now have this which is better.

```
[
  "0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062\":\"1",
  "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA\":\"1",
  "0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA\":\"1"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JmesPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) is not able to count the frequencies of items in a list. You'll have to use other tool. For example,

- [uniq](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) and awk

```bash
shell> cat data.json | jq '.data.votes[].voter' | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
"0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062" 1
"0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA" 2
```

---

- Python

```py
shell> cat count_voters.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3.9

import jmespath
import json
import yaml
import collections


with open('data.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
s = json.loads(data)
print(yaml.dump(s))

voters = jmespath.search('data.votes[*].voter', s)
print(yaml.dump(voters))

voters_freq = dict(collections.Counter(voters))
print(yaml.dump(voters_freq))
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ./count_voters.py
data:
  votes:
  - id: '0x0d185'
    voter: '0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062'
  - id: '0xf141aa'
    voter: '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'
  - id: '0xf141aa'
    voter: '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'

- '0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062'
- '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'
- '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'

'0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062': 1
'0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA': 2
```

---

- Ansible

```yaml
shell> cat count_voters.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    voters: "{{ s.data.votes|json_query('[].voter') }}"
    voters_freq: "{{ voters|community.general.counter }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: data.json
        name: s
    - debug:
        var: s
    - debug:
        var: voters
    - debug:
        var: voters_freq
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook count_voters.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  s:
    data:
      votes:
      - id: '0x0d185'
        voter: '0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062'
      - id: '0xf141aa'
        voter: '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'
      - id: '0xf141aa'
        voter: '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  voters:
  - '0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062'
  - '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'
  - '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  voters_freq:
    '0x4Aad3544bE38067F534b6B516f9E645D495c4062': 1
    '0xB01f126C9041CC230e91378d688450Db4c3510cA': 2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, looks like I'm trying to use the wrong tool.

Comment: The result of  *JmesPath* [Wildcard Expressions](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#wildcard-expressions) is always a list. This is what *JmesPath* is good for. Depending on the use case, there are other tools to do their part. See [software tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

Comment: Thank you for sharing!
I am building a graphql UI tool to allow users to input a graphql query, endpoint, and jmespath query (or something similar) to extract just the list of Id's. 
I need to return it to another service in the format {"0x123": "1". "0x321": "1", "0x234": "3"} and I was assessing if this was possible just with JMESpath. 
What I'm thinking now is I ask the user to insert the JMESpath query to fetch the voters in the array (like what you've done) and hard-code the counting logic serverside.

Comment: Thanks again for sharing the software tools wikipedia link, it's a great read